# HTML and JavaScript: Change button text (Toggle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change a button's text, however I think the issue I don't understand is how to change it back using separate files. I need to use jQuery to toggle pictures. This will hide the image and show the image. The button is "hard coded" I think in both the HTML and JavaScript.

The button is showing "hide" to initially hide the image. Once the button is clicked the image disappears and the button's text turns to "Show". However it will not turn back to "hide".

HTML:

```
<img src="sky.jpg" id="sky">
<input type='button' onclick="js/toggle.js" id="skybutton" value="Hide">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/toggle.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#skybutton').click(function() {
    $("#sky").toggle();
    $(skybutton).val('Show');
});
```

Comment: have you tried adding a conditional to check the name of the label ?

Comment: you dont need onclick in html, just connect script to html on end of body tag

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to stackoverflow Shepard!!

You need little bit of logic in your javascript in order to make this work both ways:

```
<img src="sky.jpg" id="sky">
<input type='button' onclick="js/toggle.js" id="skybutton" value="Hide">
```

Here in the click function is where you need magic to happen:
Try this code:

```
$('#skybutton').click(function() {
    $("#sky").toggle();
    if($(this).val() === 'Hide'){
        $(this).val('Show');
    }else{
        $(this).val('Hide');
    }
});
```

So what is happening above is that you already have a click function attached to the button so with in the function you can refer to that button as `this` and you can check what the value of the button is.

Your if statement goes hey button `if` your value is 'Hide' change the value to 'Show' and else your value must be 'Show' so change it back to 'Hide' let me know if I can clear anything else up for you. Good luck with the project

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using an if else statement say:

```
$('#skybutton').click(function() {
    If($(this).val() == "hide") {
        $("#sky").hide();
        $(this).val("Show")
    } else {
        $("#sky").show();
        $(this).val("hide")
    }

});
```

Comment: Was using my phone and barely noticed some syntax typo error the val is in small letters not capita letters

Answer (score 0):

In support of I am Cavic, just a more readable version

```
$('#skybutton').click(() => {
    $("#sky").toggle()
    if ($(this).val() === "hide") {
        $(this).val("show")
        return
    }
    $(this).val("hide")
})
```

Comment: thank you for the support have ever your code most likely won't work for the poster he will need to use es6 processor for => notation which by his original post you can tell he is not using also your last line `.Val("hide") will throw an error

Comment: 'readable' is a matter of opinion, I prefer @I am Cavic's solution.

Comment: @I am Cavic, ya sure the `Val()` was a typo. Support for the feature is pretty good, a 86.68% of browsers supports it source : https://caniuse.com. @Poul Bak, yes you're totally right readability is a opinion and it is something we as developers should promote.